# Instance of 'Future<String>' How to solve it

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using flutter and I am trying to get a value from shared_preferences that I had set before, and display it in a text widget. but  get Instance of Future instead of the value. here is my code:

```
String _recog(imglib.Image img) {
    List input = imageToByteListFloat32(img, 112, 128, 128);
    input = input.reshape([1, 112, 112, 3]);
    List output = List(1 * 192).reshape([1, 192]);
    interpreter.run(input, output);
    output = output.reshape([192]);
    e1 = List.from(output);

    return compare(e1).toString();
  }

  Future<String> compare(List currEmb) async {
    var firdoc = await _firestore
        .collection('allfaces')
        .doc(_auth.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('faces')
        .get();
    if (data.length == 0) return Future.value("No Face saved");
    double minDist = 999;
    double currDist = 0.0;
    String predRes = "NOT RECOGNIZED";
    for (var doc in firdoc.docs) {
      currDist = 0.0;
      for (int i = 0; i < currEmb.length; i++) {
        currDist += (currEmb[i] - doc.data()['embedding'][i]).abs().toDouble();
      }
      if (currDist < minDist) {
        minDist = currDist;
        predRes = doc.data()['name'];
      }
    }
    print(minDist.toString() + " " + predRes);
    return predRes;
  }
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. What is exactly the issue you are encountering here? what is the expected behaviour and what is the actual one?

Comment: Are you looking for `return await compare(e1)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken, you try to save an image in shared_preferences.The string who result to convertion is so long but shared_preferences has a storage limit